# How to split xml file with perl?

Tags: xml, perl

My code

```
use strict;

use warnings;

my $filename = '263.xml';

open(my $fh, $filename)

perl -p -i -e '$fh if /<caldata chopper="on"/ "(\d+)"/; print $fh;'
```

But

```
Warning: Use of "-p" without parentheses is ambiguous at a1.pl line 7.
syntax error at a1.pl line 7, near ")

perl "
Execution of a1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I want to separate line with

```
caldata chopper="on"
```

and caldata chopper="off"
into separate files.
This is the whole line

```
<caldata chopper="on" gain_1="0" gain_2="0" gain_3="0" impedance="(0,0)">
```

Comment: What you posted as "_My code_" makes no sense.  Do you literally have a line with `perl ...` in a script?  The `perl` an unquoted bareword in a script. The regex itself is fine (no need to escape `"` or anything else).  However, how `$fh` is used is wrong -- it's a filehandle.  Also, you are clearly missing a `;` on that `line 7` from (the first) error.

Comment: @zdim Yes,I am beginner with perl.How should the line look like?

Comment: OK.  It is far from valid Perl. `open` line needs a `;`. The `$fh` is a _filehandle_, which gives access to the resource (file) -- you use it to read data from said resource, not to print it. So you'd need a loop like `while(<$fh>)`. There is no keyword `perl` in the language. The statement `$fh if /.../` makes no sense, I don't see what you mean by it. The firts part of the regex, `/.../`, is fine, but the rest (second `/.../`) does not make sense.  Etc. I'd suggest to go through the basics of the language first.

Comment: When I use "_no sense_" I mean to say that it doesn't conform to the most basic language rules and that I can't even see what you want to do with it.  I don't mean to be offensive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clarify why the posted code "doesn't make sense", `perl -p -i -e` is something you would type on the command line by itself, not something which goes into a Perl program.  Basically, the `perl -p -i -e '...'` is itself the program to run.  [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) explains in greater detail, but:

- `-p` puts a loop around the `...` code which runs it against each line of the input file
- `-i` means to edit the input file in place (instead of creating any new files for output)
- `-e` tells `perl` that you're providing executable code as part of the command line, rather than running a program from a file

The correct way to do what you were attempting would be something like (warning - untested code):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '<', '263.xml' or die "Can't open input file: $!";
open my $out_on, '>', 'on.xml' or die "Can't open 'on' output file: $!";
open my $out_off, '>', 'off.xml' or die "Can't open 'off' output file: $!";

while (my $line = <$in>) {
  $line =~ /<caldata chopper="(on|off)"/;
  if ($1 eq 'on') {
    print $out_on, $line;
  } elsif ($1 eq 'off') {
    print $out_off, $line;
  }
}
```

Note, however, that this technique will not create proper XML output files.  It will just generate files containing lists of `caldata` elements without any of the additional surrounding elements needed to have a single, well-formed XML document.  If you need a well-formed XML document, I would suggest taking a look at [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) rather than attempting to parse or generate XML by hand.